# how to add url in href attribute in ngb-pagination

Tags: angular

For my blog website, I am using ngb-pagination from ng-bootstrap Angular package. I want to be able to set the absolute url in href attribute in `<a>` tag in the pagination component. So that the crawlers knows the url. Please can someone help on this. Thanks in advance.

```
<ngb-pagination
  class="d-flex justify-content-center"
  [pageSize]="pageSize"
  [collectionSize]="collectionSize"
  [maxSize]="5"
  [boundaryLinks]="false"
  [ellipses]="false"
  [rotate]="true"
  [(page)]="page"
></ngb-pagination>
```

Comment: You are assuming that each page in your pagination will have a different URL, I think that is not the case.

Comment: you can have look here https://www.justinmind.com/blog/ each page in the pagination has different URL.

Comment: And you are sure that this is done with an `ngb-pagination` element?

Comment: No but I want to achieve the same using ngb-pagination. possible?

Comment: I think not as easily as you would like. Each button in that pagination would have to be an `<a href>` or at least something that manipulates the url and then you'd need to put a routing mechanism in place to tell your angular app what happens if someone opens your url for a specific page. read about routing [here](https://angular.io/guide/router). however, I'd wonder why exactly you want to have individual urls for those pages in the first place. The intention of angular is a single page application and the url of that can of course be found by crawlers

Comment: For crawlers which doesn't support js, need an url in the page so they can follow and index them. I will have urls in my second page and usually crawlers ping my main page and check for available urls to index them. Hope you know how the SEO crawlers works.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone looking for an answer, here is how I have done.

I have created a new Angular component called custom paginator by extending the class [NgbPagination](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/master/src/pagination/pagination.ts) and in template of custom paginator I have pasted whatever available in NgbPagination template. To add href in `<a>` tag, I have done modification as I require in template and it is working as expected.

**UPDATE**

Just incase if anyone looking for the code for more clarity. Below is my component code where I have extended 3rd party library

```
export class CustomPaginatorComponent extends NgbPagination {
  @Input('href') baseUrl: string;
  @Input('category') category: string;
  @Input('subCategory') subCategory: string;

  getHrefUrl(pageNumber: number) {
  // your logic here
    return hrefUrl;
  }
}
```

copy template code of 3rd party library which you extended and paste it in  this newly created component CustomPaginatorComponent's template and do the modification in template as per your need. In my case, I have added a new function called 'getHrefUrl' to get href url in component and used it in the template as below.Hope this helps.

```
    <a
      aria-label="Previous"
      i18n-aria-label="@@ngb.pagination.previous-aria"
      class="page-link"
      href="{{ getHrefUrl(page - 1) }}"
      [attr.tabindex]="previousDisabled() ? '-1' : null"
      [attr.aria-disabled]="previousDisabled() ? 'true' : null"
    >
```

Comment: Can your share how did you handle it ? i am facing same issue.

Comment: @Shakir - bit delayed , but I added the code now. Hope this helps you.